# KnockoutJS, how to update view model using HTML5 content editable?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="list" data-bind="foreach: list">
    <li class="title" data-bind="text:title" contenteditable="true"></li>
    <li class="item" data-bind="text:item" contenteditable="true"></li>
</ul>
<button type="button">Save</button>
```

**JS:**

```
var data = {
  "list": [{
    "title" : "title one",
    "item"  : "item one"
    }]
}

    var viewModel= 
    {
        list : ko.observable(data.list)
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);


    $("button").on("click", function(){
        var vm = viewModel;

        ko.applyBindings(vm);
        var data = ko.toJSON(vm);

        console.log(data);
    });
```

However when I do this I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element. 
knockout-3.1.0.js:58
```

What I would like to do is change the text of one of the items and have it save to the view model when I click the save button.

[image]

**FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/sr4Fg/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things.

1. only call applyBindings once, then ko will sync data for you.
2. you don't need to create a save button, ko sync data automatically.
3. your title and item are NOT ko.observable, hence ko has no way to auto-update it for you.
4. ko "text" binding is kind of one way binding, it only updates view when your value changes. You need to use "value" binding in an input tag to get two way binding.
5. right now, there is no existing ko binding supporting contenteditable. You may build a custom bindingHandler for it, but beware it's tricky to get contenteditable change event.
6. you list should be an observableArray.

Here is the working example with "value" binding: http://jsfiddle.net/sr4Fg/41/

```
<ul class="list" data-bind="foreach: list">
  <li class="title"><input data-bind="value:title" /></li>
  <li class="item"><input data-bind="value:item" /></li>
</ul>
<button type="button">Save</button>

var viewModel= 
{
  list : ko.observableArray([{
    "title" : ko.observable("title one"),
    "item"  : ko.observable("item one")
  }])
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);


$("button").on("click", function(){
  var data = ko.toJSON(viewModel);
  console.log(data);
});
```

Understand you may load JSON data from ajax call, it's tedious to change all the values into ko.observable. Try http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html if you need.

Comment: Well this answers the question I asked and seems to work. But it is apparent I may need to re-think how I am doing things. Thank you.